# Users reporting JQuery setTimeout functionality not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

Apologies that this is somewhat of an open question but after research hopefully experience will identify an issue.

I've written some JQuery code that shows a modal ("*Are you still there?*") dialog box after 20 minutes of user inactivity.  If the user doesn't respond to this within 5 minutes, they get logged out. If they click the link to indicate they're still active, an (ASP.Net) endpoint is hit via JavaScript to validate and refresh their login cookie.

If they fail to click on the "*I'm still here*" link within 5 minutes, then they're automatically logged out.

It works perfectly for me on Firefox/Chrome/Edge, but some users on Edge are reporting that the modal dialog box never appears, and so during their usage of the interface they randomly get logged out without any warning.

Based on the following code, is there any reason why Edge users may encounter this behaviour?  There may be something glaringly wrong in the code that would actually affect all browsers, but I can't find anything.

```
<script>

    var modalTimer;                 // A timer that displays the "Are you still there?" dialog
    var logOutTimer;                // A timer that automatically logs the user out
    var delayUntilWarning = 20;     // Number of minutes before displaying the "Are you still there?" dialog
    var delayUntilLogOut = 5;       // Number of minutes before logging the user out

    function StartTimer() {
        clearTimeout(modalTimer);
        clearTimeout(logOutTimer);
        modalTimer = setTimeout('ShowLogOutModal()', (delayUntilWarning * 60000)); // Starts the timer to display the modal dialog after inactivity
    }

    // Shows the "Are you still there" dialog
    function ShowLogOutModal() {
        
        $('#pnl_modalBg > .modalDialog > p:eq(2)').show();
        $('#pnl_modalBg > .modalDialog > p:eq(3)').hide();
        $('#pnl_modalBg').fadeIn(100);
        logOutTimer = setTimeout('LogOut()', (delayUntilLogOut * 60000)); // Starts the timer to log them out automatically
    }
    
    function LogOut() {
        window.location = '/Logout';
    }

    function StillHereClicked() {
        $('#pnl_modalBg > .modalDialog > p:eq(2)').hide(); // Hide reset counter link
        $('#pnl_modalBg > .modalDialog > p:eq(3)').show(); // Show "loading..." text
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/timeout.ashx", // ASP.Net endpoint to get/set cookie expiry and return string "Extended" if all is valid
            dataType: "text",
            cache: false
            })
            .done(function (data) {
                if (data == "Extended") {
                    StartTimer();
                    $('#pnl_modalBg').fadeOut(100);
                } else {
                    LogOut();
                }
            })
            .fail(function (xhr, textStatus) { // Cookie expired or not present - log user out
                LogOut();
            }
        );
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        StartTimer();   // Start timer automatically when page loads
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Maybe this is not related to the question but you should not write `setTimeout('ShowLogOutModal()', (delayUntilWarning * 60000))` like this. Your first parameter here is javascript in quotation marks so javascript has to evaluate this string when the time has finished. This could be considered unsafe by some browsers so the function would not get called. You can use your function directly as the first parameter of `setTimeout` for example like this: `setTimeout(LogOut, (delayUntilLogOut * 60000))` without wrapping it up in quotation marks.

Comment: Good feedback, thanks.  I'll do that.